# Which one is correct? 给我打电话/打电话给我

Tags: grammar, mandarin, sentence-structure

can you help me which one is correct and which one is wrong?

1. 你给我打个电话
2. 你给我打电话
3. 你给我电话
4. 你打给我个电话
5. 你打给我电话
6. 你打电话给我

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Narges, thank you for posting, please make sure to take a look at [How to Ask](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Usually it's better if you provide a bit more of context and explain what you find confusing, so that others can provide more relevant answers.

Answer (score 1):

1. 你给我打个电话 - good, colloquial
2. 你给我打电话 - good, slightly more formal
3. 你给我电话 - what, as a birthday present?
4. 你打给我个电话 - weird
5. 你打给我电话 - weird
6. 你打电话给我 - OK (a little more emphasis on 打电话, seems like 给我 is almost an afterthought)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

你给我打个电话 correct

你给我打电话 also means YOU ARE ASKING ME TO CALL SOMEONE. 你给我打电话(給)(某人、某公司,etc). Use first one is better if you are talking about "GIVE ME A CALL".

你给我电话 Hmm...you can use this to ask someone's phone number. (电話 could have 3 meanings. 1.telephone or cell phone 2.phone number. 3. Phone Call)

你打给我个电话 It sounds more like a past event. (昨天)你打给我个电话

你打给我电话 (refer to previous one.) (昨天)你打给我电话

你打电话给我 It also sounds like a past event. (昨天)你打电话给我

You could just say "Call我" "給我個電話".

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, HungYu Chang.